# Failed to create desktop entry in pycharm 4.0.3

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

After downloading `pycharm 4.0.3.zip`, I extracted it in the home folder and renamed it to `.pycharm 4.0.3`.

Then I opened a terminal and went to `/.pycharm 4.0.3/pycharm 4.0.3/bin` and ran the command `sh pycharm.sh`.

And after that, when I tried to create an desktop entry form *Configure>>create desktop entry*, it's showing:

> Failed to create desktop entry
>   Unable to locate suitable startup script in '/home/rimon/.pycharm 4.0.3/pycharm 4.0.3/bin'.

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04.

**EDIT**

It's now working, the steps I flowed :

1. I downloaded a new pycharm-4.0.4.tar.gz file
2. Then I made this two files named fsnotifier & fsnotifier64 executable, which is located in the /home/rimon/.pycharm-4.0.4/bin folder
3. Then I made pycharm.sh executable, located in the same folder.
4. Then ran command cd /home/rimon/.pycharm-4.0.4/bin and after that ./pycharm.sh

And finally created the desktop entry normally from Configure>>create desktop entry

Comment: Don't Extract in `\home`. It is not the same as `\Home`. Extract it in `\home\rimon`. It will work

Comment: sorry my bad, I actually extracted it in /home/rimon

Comment: Check if there is any probs in the spelling. If there is a space you have to use `\ `

Comment: checked it, found nothing unusual :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use this command in your computer's terminal:

```
sudo su

==> enter your system password

cd /.pycharm 4.0.3/pycharm 4.0.3/bin

chmod +x pycharm.sh

./pycharm.sh
```

I hope it will work . Inform me if any complexity occur .

Comment: Also need to make these two files fsnotifier & fsnotifier64 executable. Thanks Anyway :)

Comment: Obviously you have to do this . I don't describe this cause it's basic need to run those commands . By the way , best of luck !

Answer (score 2):

If you're using Ubuntu you should download a tar.gz archive, which is supposed to contain Ubuntu installation files.
Once extracted and installed, if you can't see PyCharm desktop entry do the following:

Open a new terminal and run:

```
sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/pycharm.desktop
```

Don't worry if that file doesn't exists, it's normal...

Write in Gedit following lines:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=PyCharm 4.0.3
Comment=Start PyCharm 4.0.3
Exec= gksudo /home/.pycharm 4.0.3/pycharm 4.0.3/bin 
Icon= "Icon Image location"
Categories=Application
Type=Application
Terminal=false
```

Note: 
Exec line should contain folder location where you installed/extracted Pycharm files from tar.gz archive
Icon line should contain an image's location which you want to be desktop entry's icon

After saving the file close Gedit and run following command in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Once command has finished press Windows button and type pycharm. Pycharm launcher should show up. You should be able to launch it from there, move it on Applications Bar, on Desktop or wherever you want.

Good luck with Python :)

Comment: Accepted answer solved the problem for me. Thanks Anyways !!

Answer (score 1):

The .zip file is a Windows distribution of PyCharm. You need to download the .tar.gz file if you're running PyCharm on Linux.

Comment: I prefer zip instead of tar.gz so actually the .zip file was made my me earlier after extracting it from the .tar.gz for keeping it on my HDD.

Comment: The .zip and .tar.gz distributions have different contents. It's not a matter of personal preference; to have PyCharm working correctly on Linux, you need the .tar.gz distribution.

Comment: Though I downloaded a new .tar.gz file but I checked that the folder I extracted from the .zip also working fine if I follow steps 2-5.
Thanks Anyway. :)

Answer (score 1):

Its now working, the steps I flowed :

1. I downloaded a new `pycharm-4.0.4.tar.gz` file
2. Then I made this two files named ***fsnotifier & fsnotifier64*** executable, which is located in the `/home/rimon/.pycharm-4.0.4/bin` folder
3. Then I made `pycharm.sh` executable, located in the same folder.
4. Then ran command `cd /home/rimon/.pycharm-4.0.4/bin` and after that `./pycharm.sh`
5. And finally created the desktop entry normally from Configure>>create desktop entry

Now it is working Fine :)